# Teradata: Best way to search items using wildcard

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to search items using where clause like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE ITEMID LIKE '%[0-9][abc][0-9]%'
```

What I am trying to achieve is to retrieve data having `itemID` with alphabets of only `'a'`, `'b'`, or `'c'`, starting and ending with number in the middle of alphanumerical value.

For instance, `'337Z112'` shouldn't be retrieved because it is not `'a'`, `'b'`, or `'c'`.

Other example is `'edcb9a9b'` which should be retrieved because it contains `'9a9'`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Teradata, you would need to use [`REGEXP_SIMILAR()`](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/1DcoER_KpnGTfgPinRAFUw/ptxsLmg1THjUw9eZiS~hvw) to compare agains a regular expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE RegExp_Similar(itemid, '.*\d[abc]\d.*', 'i') = 1;
```

NB : `\d` is a shortcut for `[0-9]` (the *digits* character class)